most lightweight front end latex for Ubuntu
I recently upgraded to the newest LTS verion of Ubuntu. Since then, my latex front end, Texmaker, is clogging my system (i.e., it eats 50-123% of my CPU % under loading when I compile) and driving me nuts.  I reinstalled Texlive since then but still I am having issues.
This question in related to [1], where we learn that Texlive is the go to for the backend of linux (or Ubuntu).  In this question I ask what is the most lightweight front end for linux. For me, I define light weight as in [2]: a light-weight front end is one that uses lower memory and/or has less processor-speed requirements than a more "feature-rich" front end. The lower demands on hardware ideally result in a more responsive machine, and/or allow devices with fewer system resources (e.g. older or embedded hardware) to be used productively.
[1] Which LaTeX to install on Linux?
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides - you can use any text editor you like, you don't need to have anything GUI based at all

which editor is currently causing your problems?

And what exactly does is clogging my system and driving me nuts. entail?

Texmaker is my current install

clogging system := CPU usage goes through the roof

Related to the comment of Joseph Wright above: I use gedit as frontend for LaTeX, it is very lightweight and suitable for editing LaTeX documents.

an editor shouldn't take any cpu time at all really so something seems wrong with your setup, but you can use any editor, I use emacs, but you can use nano or visual studio code or ....

an editor should spend 99% of its time sitting doing nothing waiting for you to hit a key, so  it may have largish memory requirements for editing buffers but should be using no cpu cycles

To be clear, the CPU loading only occurs when I compile. I switched to Gummi and the problem has decreased. Is still not as good as I would like... but much better. To be continued

But an editor doesn't compile anything, it just runs tex. Check top or similar to see what is running. Changing editor will make no difference if you set up the new editor to run the same tex process.

Anecodetely, I changed from Texmaker to Gummi and my loading problem reduced by about 50%. There may be some installation issue that made Texmaker clog me up. Anyway, the answer provided below has additionally ammeliorated the situation. I did do top FYI. But nothing stood out. I also checked diagonistally my computer to see that there was not a hardware issue.

The editor you use is irrelevant to the resources used for compilation. The same document is compiled the same way by the same binaries, if you use the same engine and options. Switching editor can't affect compilation time unless one or other of them does something additional while you are compiling.
Of course, if an editor itself takes a bunch of resources, adding the resources needed to compile may be too much, even though the resources needed to compile would be OK on their own. But the process itself is nothing to do with the editor.
If compilation is taking too many resources or too much time, you need to investigate why that is and whether you can reduce the load. The resources and time required for compilation depend on the

engine (pdfTeX, LuaTeX etc.);
format (plain, latex etc.);
content.

LuaTeX and XeTeX are more demanding than pdfTeX.
But the main cause of longer/more intense compilations is generally the content of your document. For example, the following will all require more computational resources and extend compilation times:

tables which use tabularray;
loading many large, complex packages;
plots e.g. pgfplots, tikz etc.;
diagrams e.g. metapost, pstricks, tikz etc.;

the particular way you use tikz e.g. extensive use of pgfmath, bend in arrows, hobby, graphing etc.


packages which use the above e.g. forest, prooftrees etc.;
use of a large number of large fonts (e.g. many opentype fonts);
inclusion of large image files;
unnecessary recompilation e.g. running biber even if the referencing hasn't changed.

Obviously length makes a difference, too, but the additional resources required for another 100 pages of text are trivial in comparison with those required for a few pages of some other elements.
You can mitigate the problem in many ways. For example,

externalise images produced with packages such as tikz;
avoid tabularray, at least for simpler tables;
use draft mode to avoid including external images;
use \include and \includeonly to compile only the part of the document you're working on;
don't load packages or fonts you don't need.

More recent versions of LaTeX are also more demanding than older versions. The same is true of many packages. Not all: the oldest version of prooftrees would be slower and more resource-hungry than the current version, for example.

Very good answer. Your suggestions have helped already. Follow-up question. How about mdframed? Is that particularly intensive?

@MichaelLevy I don't use it much. which framing method are you using? I assume that would be one critical factor.

framing regime:     \newtheorem{theoremin}{Theorem}[chapter] \newenvironment{theorem}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]\begin{theoremin}}{\end{theoremin}\end{mdframed} \end{minipage}}

@MichaelLevy I think it depends on whether you told it to use a non-default framing method when loading the package. so if you asked for tikz or ps etc., it will load (and use?) that. if you didn't or asked for tex or whatever, it won't. but not even using tikz for something that simple should add that much to the compilation demands.
